# Difference between using a gerund and using to + verb root

Tags: infinitives, gerunds

As an objective (or subjective). "Being a teacher" vs "to be a teacher". What is the difference between gerund and 'to' + verb root ?

My dream is being a teacher.
My dream is to be a teacher.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I don't understand your question. Can you try again to identify/explain the question that you want people here to answer?

Comment: Related question, [The choice between the gerund and the infinitive in a certain construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88014/the-choice-between-the-gerund-and-the-infinitive-in-a-certain-construction).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use of gerund or infinitive after "is"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328588/when-to-use-of-gerund-or-infinitive-after-is)

Answer (score 1):

These are possible structures:
Gerund is generally used to refer to reality or a fact, but infinitive is used for wishes, possibilities, dreams and abstract ideas.

1. My dream is to become a teacher.
2. To become a teacher is my dream.
3. Becoming a teacher is my dream.(less common)

However, your sentence "My dream is being a teacher" is less common.

Comment: @Rathony- I mean gerund is commonly used for referring to reality or an actual experience.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about about usage differences here, unless you're being really picky. I think there are very few people who would make a distinction between the two. If you're already a teacher, however, "my dream is to be a teacher" could be awkward, as it sort of implies that you're not a teacher yet. "My dream is being a teacher" can be used regardless of whether you're already a teacher or not, though (although personally, I'd only use it if I was already a teacher; that's just my personal preference).

Comment: @Rathony- "Driving his own car costs a lost of money." This is a fact that he has a car, and this is a fact he should pay a lot of money for his gasoline. However, in "To drive his own car is his great dream." it is just a dream to have a car.

Comment: @Mani so are you saying that "to drive his own car costs a lot of money," does not refer to a "reality or an actual experience?"