# Gerund versus infinitive

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

I wonder if someone could offer feedback about the use and meaning difference between the use of infinitive and gerund

1. Being an artist is admitting you are lost and not wanting to be found.
2. Being an artist is to admit you are lost and not want to be found.
3. To be an artist is to admit you are lost and not want to be found.
4. To be an artist is admitting you are lost and not wanting to be found.

As an English speaker, I would incline toward, 
To be an artist is to admit you are lost and not want to be found.
as in
to be poor is to be close to something!
although in the sentence
To be an artist is admitting you are lost and not wanting to be found.
there seems to me to be an implied, like or akin, eg, to be an artist is like admitting.
but I wonder if there is a subtler meaning or rule that I am missing!
Thanks in advance for any pointers
Richard

Comment: The sentences you give are not all grammatical. There are four clauses, which can vary in their structure, and modify one another in different ways, so these are not all the variations possible. It's hard to figure out how to answer this question.  There are [general, very rough, guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/328595/15299) for complement usage: gerunds correspond to events, while infinitives correspond to situation types. _That_-clauses correspond to propositions. That's what you asked about.